# jQuery: callback doesn't work right

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery so forgive me (and correct me too please) if I say something wrong here.

I have this code and the callback is being executed right the moment the element is clicked, and not after the slideUp has finished:

```
$('.close-button').click(function(){
    $('.click-menu div').slideUp(3000, function() {
        $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','1');
    });     
});
```

Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's likely happening is that any *already* hidden `<div>` elements will execute the callback immediately, since their animations to hide are complete immediately, you can avoid this by only sliding up [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) elements, like this:

```
$('.close-button').click(function(){
    $('.click-menu div:visible').slideUp(3000, function() {
        $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','1');
    });     
});
```

Comment: +1 A little off-topic, but perhaps also worth pointing out that the callback will fire once *per matched element*, which would seem to be a redundant exercise here.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks again Nick, and your explanations are very helpful as well.

Comment: @Ricardo - welcome :) @patrick - definitely good to note, if this isn't the one-at-a-time visible situations you may very well want another approach.

Answer (score 0):

No the callback call once the animation is complete

you can use the jquery documentation it's realy helpful

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: I don't think this was the question...it is happening instantly, the OP is asking *why* it's happening instantly.

Comment: yes, and his code matches the documentation perfectly. He is questioning WHY the callback is calling immediately, he knows it should callback once complete.

Comment: Correct, I didn't know why it was being executed immediately, until Nick's answer :)